# Preserving indentation with glue

Tags: r, r-glue

When using the R package `glue`, the following code

```
glue("foo\n  bar")
```

results in

```
foo
bar
```

However, I would prefer it to produce

```
foo
  bar
```

I could do the following

```
. <- "  "
glue("foo\n{.}bar")
```

but it is ugly. Interestingly, the following works as intended:

```
glue('
foo
  bar')
```

but for some strange reason the following does not:

```
glue('foo
  bar')
```

Can you explain to me this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glue('foo\n   bar',.trim = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this topic doing some research

The `tidyverse` github discussed this. They stated that this would need to be done to attain the desired output

```
glue("
    foo
      bar
     ")
```

Putting the link to the source in the comments on my answer

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/glue#leading-whitespace-and-blank-lines-from-the-first-and-last-lines-are-automatically-trimmed

Comment: Thank you, I mentioned that already in my edit in parallel with your answer, but I was looking for a way to achieve this on one line. Otherwise my code looks ugly ;-)